# Does an embargo on a Civilisation stop trade routes with their team mates?

Tags: civilization-5

The description suggests that it would:

> No Trade Routes can be established between the chosen Civilization and any other Civilization. Any such Trade Routes are ended and must be reassigned.

However, trade routes between team mates behave like internal trade routes in all other cases.

Would they be exempt from the embargo or not?

Comment: It may depend on the trade route type. I mean are the route using road/rail or those camel/boat things?

Comment: @Jouramie Trade routes are using Caravan/Cargo Ship units. You're thinking of capital connections, which are completely different and never affected by embargo.

Comment: Also is this assuming BNW expansion since that is what added trade routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got myself into the exact situation I describe. My team mate has been embargoed: all (food and production) trade routes between us have been cancelled and cannot be re-established.

So the answer is actually **Yes**.

Comment: "The answer is actually yes" implies I said this was false, when in fact I did not.

Comment: You didn't say it was true either.

Answer (score 1):

Embargo impacts all external/international trade routes. If you have ever been embargoed you can see that you are still capable of sending trade routes **to your own cities** for food/production/religion spread(pressure), but nowhere else.

Worth noting that embargo does not actually impact your ability to trade goods such as gpt/luxury or strategic resources.

Comment: Yes, but I've never been embargoed during a team game. Have you?

Comment: Yes - although it is usually rare since your team tends to vote to avoid that from happening. But there are some instances where you are say against Greece with a ton of votes and they overpower the vote.